# Python Convert space delimted List to dataframe with individual columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a list into a dataframe but I keep getting error.

Error: 
"ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 8)"

The reason this is happening is because the first column sometimes has spaces in the name. Is there a way to extract first column then merge it back. This column has names with spaces in it and it messes up the column count

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finviz.com/futures.ashx')

search_deltaprice=[]
result_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tile_change pull-right"]/..')

for element in result_elements:
        search_result = element.text
        search_deltaprice.append(search_result)


df = pd.DataFrame(search_deltaprice, columns =['Ticker', 'Price', 'HighLabel','HighPrice','LowLabel','LowPrice','Change','PctChange'], dtype = str)
```

I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(search_deltaprice)
```

But this returned a dataframe that had all the data in 1 column I want each data element in its own column the space is the delimiter. Type list does not have a split method.

Comment: String of day2 has 9 values but day1 and day3 have 8. Is that right?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting each string in the list and use that to generate the dataframe.
For the current example you need to find the right character to split and that is "\n"

```
driver.quit()
splitted_search=[x.split("\n") for x in search_deltaprice]
df = pd.DataFrame(splitted_search, columns =['Ticker', 'Price', 'HighLabel','HighPrice','LowLabel','LowPrice','Change','PctChange'], dtype = str)
```

PS: Remember to close your webdriver.

Comment: Thank you Sergio, Thanks to your Tip I realized that there are names in the first column that have spaces. This creates extra columns. Can we some how extract 1column when Parsing html and merge it back once we are done?

Comment: I guess it is easier to do the merging while you're parsing given the structure of the page than doing it after the parsing is done (but doable if there is a pattern you can find, for example the extra data was an integer between a string and a float.)

Comment: Wont work because some of the names have numbers in it. S&P  500 and the NASDAQ 100 these are the names of the first column. I guess I have to go back to the initial parse and see if I can pull the first column individually. Any ideas on how to pull that off?

Comment: Well, that comment was done without reading the new explanation. It always depends on how you extract the data. Try the modified answer.

Comment: Close webdriver? The solution worked with the web driver open. I ran it with web driver closed and it worked as well. Thank you. worked 100% Why would closing web driver matter?